# UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE gives an unexpected match

Tags: jackson, jersey-client, jackson-databind

I'm pretty new to Jackson so apologies in advance if there's an obvious solution.

I'm writing a Jersey client and I'm trying to deserialize JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "someEntity": {
        "someField": 123
    }
}
```

Now if the 'success' field didn't exist this would be pretty simple as I could just configure the ObjectMapper to use `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` and it'd deserialize the contents to SomeEntity.

My Response object looks like:

```java
public class Response<T>
{
    private boolean success;
    private T entity;

    public T getEntity()
    {
        return entity;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

Where `entity` would be...

```java
public class SomeEntity
{
    private int someField;

    public int getSomeField()
    {
        return someField;
    }
}
```

When trying to deserialize the above JSON to `Response<SomeEntity>` without any configuration I get: `Unrecognized field "someEntity" (class Response)`

I had some luck with adding `@JsonProperty("someEntity")` to the `entity` field but obviously I'd like this response class to be generic and not have to make one for every entity passed to the client.

I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm not seeing - thanks in advance.

Edit: I've also tried using `@JsonTypeInfo` to no avail.

Comment: Still trying to get this to work... All the existing solutions I've seen rely on the generic entity having a constant name. The only solution I've had success with is creating a response class for every possible entity, but obviously that's not ideal.

I need to find a way for Jackson to infer the property name from T. Alternatively, since this is the only unknown field in the JSON, would it be possible to take its child elements and map those to T?